# training random forest using caret package

Tags: random-forest, r-caret, roc

I want to use my training data to train a random forest model, but some errors occured.

The error message as below:

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities
are generated because the variables names will be converted to  X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7 . Please use factor 
levels that can be used as valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).
```

Below is my code:

```
rf.ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                    number = 10,
                    repeats = 10,
                    classProbs = TRUE,
                    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)


set.seed(256)

#train the calssification model with random forest
rf.model <- train(as.factor(response) ~ .,data = trainvals,
              method = "rf",
              trControl = rf.ctrl,
              tuneLength = 10,
              metic = "ROC")
```

The structure of trainvals is :

[image]

The class level of response is 1,2,3,4,5,6,and 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One or more of the columns in the `trainvals` data frame is not a factor type, hence the error you are getting.  You can convert all columns to factor using the following:

```
trainvals[] <- lapply(trainvals, factor)
```

Comment: Tim, Thank you. I try to use your code to train my model again, but it can not work. And I have another question. Do you know how to change the class level of 1 and 2 into cropland and forest, respectively.